# How to pass php object in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Well passing a php variable in ng-click is understood but how can i pass complete php object through ng-click function i have successfully passed JavaScript object through it but i cant pass php object any help will be appreciated. Here is my script:

```
<ul>
   <!-- Retrieving of main products -->
                            <? 
                              if(isset($products)):
                                foreach($products as $row):  

                            ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="products/<?=$row->sub_c_id?>/<?=$row->pid?>" class="title colr"><?=$row->pname?></a>
                                    <a href="products/<?=$row->sub_c_id?>/<?=$row->pid?>" class="thumb">
                                     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/<?=$row->product_pic?>" style="width:157px; height:181px;" alt="" />
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="prodbuttons">
                                        <p class="price bold"><?=$row->pprice?></p>
                                        <a class="cart upper" ng-click="addtocart(<?=$row->pid?>,'<?=$this->session->userdata('session_id'); ?>','<?=$row->pname?>',<?=$row->pprice?>,<?=$row->pquantity?>,<?=$row->sub_c_id?>,'<?=$row->product_pic?>','<?=$row->color?>','<?=$row->size?>',1)">Add to Cart</a>
                                        <a ng-click="check(<? json_encode($row) ?>)">email me</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                             <? endforeach; endif; ?>  


                            </ul>
```

I have also tried like that but it gave me error as well:

```
<a ng-click="check(<? echo json_encode($row) ?>)">email me</a>
```

Angular js script:

```
$scope.addtocart=function(pid,current_session_id,pname,pprice,pquantity,sub_c_id,product_pic,color,size,qty){
             $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
             $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
             $http.post('/product/ng_insertincart', { pid : pid, current_session_id : current_session_id, pname : pname, pprice : pprice, pquantity : pquantity,sub_c_id : sub_c_id,product_pic : product_pic,color : color,size : size, qty : qty}
                        ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            if (data.msg != '')
                            {
                                $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                                console.log(data);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                            }
                        }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                           // or server returns response with an error status.
                            $scope.errors.push(status);
                        });
        }
     $scope.check=function(argument) {
         console.log(argument);
     }
```

Comment: In my opinion you really shouldn't be mixing PHP with Angular templates at all.

Comment: i have to brother its client demand

Comment: @Vicky, your client is demanding that you inject PHP objects into your JS code?

Comment: Start by creating us a small snippet of code which shows your problem rather than your own production code.

Answer (score 1):

Yikes.  Since your client is somehow forcing you to do this then at least move the php stuff to your angular controller.  Something like:

```
var controller = function()
{
<?php 
    // Convert product objects to array then encode as json
    $items = array();
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $item = array(
            'pid' => $product->pid,
            'pprice' => $product->pprice,
            ...
        $items[] = $item;
     }
     $productsJson = json_encode($items);
?>
$scope.products = angular.fromJson('<?php echo $productsJson; ?>');
```

So now you have a proper products array in your controller and you can use good ole ng-repeat in your templates.  But even the conversion of $products to a json string does not need to be done in a template.  Do it in your main php code then just pass the string to the template.  There are also serializers that can help turning php objects into arrays: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to output the object as json which you are doing but make sure it's passed in as a string to the scope function by placing single quotes around it like so:

```
<a ng-click="check('<? echo json_encode($row) ?>')">email me</a>
```

then in your function:

```
$scope.check = function(obj) {
obj = angular.fromJson(obj);
// do something
}
```

Comment: i have console.log(obj) and it still says undefined

Comment: now the error change to this SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: since the json object is now being put in the html and it's a string you'll need to escape it.

Comment: like this would seriously mess you up <a ng-click="check('{"something":"foo"})" that's not valid so you'd have to escape it. Then in the function you'll need to first unescape it and then fromJson it.

Comment: if you make a plunker with some sample code i can help you

Comment: i will try to provide you

Comment: <a ng-click="check('{"something":"foo"})" exactly this thing is causing problem so how can i escape the values

Comment: this error come up in console <a ng-click="check('[{" pid":"22","pprice":"30000"}]')"="">  Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unterminated%20quote&p1=s%206-9%20%5B'%5B%7B%5D&p2=check('%5B%7B
    at Error (native)